# Is "as of today" a standard English expression?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, formality

Can I use "as of today" in a formal letter or essay? 
I have googled this expression and turns out it could mean two different things.

1. until today
2. starting from today

So I got suspicious that this may be one of those expressions that people use in informal contexts but it is not actually correct English! 
Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: It's standard English. You can use this idiom in both formal and informal English in the senses you have mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that phrase and I assure you that it isn't incorrect.Like you said, *"as of today"* has two meanings:

- > From the beginning up until now, including today.

  or
- > Starting today and going forward into the future.

In addition, it has another meaning, which isn't used that commonly though, as:

- > today, only.

Now, this isn't one of those phrases that are only to be used in informal contexts. Consider the following sentences:

> - As of today, most countries have abolished slavery.
> - Everybody has been seated, as of now.

These sentences are not strictly informal. So there is no issue with using it formally.